# Pandas automatically infer best dtype: str to int not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

On a dataframe with > 100 columns I want pandas (v1.4.2) to **automatically** convert all columns to the "best" dtype. According to the docs [df.convert_dtypes()](https://pandas.pyda) or [df.infer_objects()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects) should do the trick. Consider the following example:

```
>>df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["1","2"], "C":["abc","bcd"]})
>>df
   A    C
0  1  abc
1  2  bcd

>>df.dtypes
A    object
C    object
dtype: object

>>df.convert_dtypes().dtypes
A    string
C    string
dtype: object

>>df.infer_objects().dtypes
A    object
C    object
dtype: object
```

Why is column `A` not converted into `int`? What would be an alternative if I am trying the wrong pandas methods?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the documentation of [convert_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes), it seems that the method does the conversion from `Object` to `Int` correctly but cannot determine if a string object is numerical:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": pd.Series([3, 4, 5], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "B": pd.Series(["3", "4", "5"], dtype=np.dtype("O")),
        "C": pd.Series(["abc","bcd"], dtype=np.dtype("O"))
    }
)
         
>>> df.dtypes

A    object
B    object
C    object
dtype: object

>> df.convert_dtypes().dtypes

A     Int64
B    string
C    string
dtype: object
```

You can use the following as a workaround for your conversion:

```
>>> df.convert_dtypes().apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore").dtypes

A     Int64
B     int64
C    object
dtype: object
```